# Waking up a thread while sleeping

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a thread which periodically executes a task. Something like the following:

```
std::thread thr;
std::atomic<bool> keepWorking;

void stopThread() {
  keepWorking = false;
  thr.join();
}

void threadLoop() {
  while(keepWorking) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(15));
    // Do Work.
  }
}
```

The problem with this code is that `stopThread` can take up to 15 seconds. I need a mechanism to wake up the thread.

After a fast search it became clear to me that I have to use `std::condition_variable::wait_for`.

The code I currently have looks like this:

```
std::thread thr;
bool keepWorking;
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;

void stopThread() {
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mtx);
    keepWorking = false;
  }
  cv.notify_one();
  thr.join();
}

void threadLoop() {
  auto endTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

  while (true) {
    endTime += std::chrono::seconds(15);
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mtx);
      while (true) {
        if (keepWorking == false)
          return;

        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        if (now > endTime)
          break;

        auto toSleep = endTime - now;
        cv.wait_for(l, toSleep);
      }
    }
    // Do Work.
  }
}
```

With the second `while(true)` loop my intention is to protect myself against  `spurious wake-up calls`.

What are the possible problems with the above code?

Comment: It looks like `// Do Work.` is a placeholder for code you've omitted.  You'll need to include that for Code Review - or (better) make your code more general so that the user can supply the work to be done (e.g. as a "task" object, or by allowing subclassing).  Then it might be complete enough for review.

Comment: @toby-speight _Then it might be complete enough for review._ I think the code is complete as it is, since `// Do Work.` is a placeholder for any code.

Comment: [help/on-topic] says, "*In order to give good advice, we need to see real, concrete code, and understand the context in which the code is used. Generic code (such as code containing placeholders like `foo`, `MyClass`, or `doSomething()`) leaves too much to the imagination.*"

Comment: @toby-speight That is the point, leave place to the imagination. `// Do Work.` is not relevant to the question. How about `// Do Work.` being `std::cout << "@toby-speight is not helpful." << std::endl;`? is that enough?

Comment: Is that what your real code contains?  If so, please edit so that what you've posted accurately reflects that.  As I said, it might be better for the function to accept a user-passed function there.

Comment: No, my real code does not contain that. I understand your suggestion about accepting a user-passed function and I think it is a good suggestion, but it is not relevant to my question. If I update the code sample to accept a user-passed function, it will become bulkier and it will not focus on the problem itself, which is having a thread which periodically executes a task and can be terminated without blocking. I am not asking how to improve my code(meaning how to make it more modular or reusable).

Comment: You seem to have an unclosed brace in your `ThreadLoop`.

Comment: @VisualMelon true, I`ve updated the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Missing headers

The code as presented won't compile, because many of the required definitions are missing:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
```

## Global variables

I think it would be better to take those global variables and package them into an object, so that it's possible to have more than one interruptible worker in your program.  Then it would look something more like:

```
class worker
{
    std::thread thr;
    bool keepWorking;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;

public:
    worker()
        : thr{&worker::threadLoop, this},
          keepWorking{true},
          mtx{},
          cv{}
    {}

    void stopThread();

private:

    static void threadLoop(worker *w);
};
```

## Unfinished code

This comment suggests that the code isn't yet finished (and therefore not ready for review).

> ```
>    // Do Work.
> ```

Moreover, it suggests that the loop will only ever execute a single, fixed block of code, which makes it very inflexible.  Instead, we should allow the caller to provide the work to be done:

```
template<typename Func>
class worker
{
    std::thread thr;
    bool keepWorking;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    Func f;

public:
    worker(Func f)
        : thr{&worker::threadLoop, this},
          keepWorking{true},
          mtx{},
          cv{},
          f{std::move(f)}
    {}
```

Then the comment becomes useful:

```
        // Do some work
        w->f();
```

## Choice of names

`l` is a very poor choice of names.  I'd prefer `lock`, or anything that doesn't look like a number.

## Excess complexity

Instead of computing `toSleep`, why not use `wait_until()` instead of `wait_for()`?  We can keep the mutex locked outside the loop, allowing the interrupting thread access only during the condition-variable wait; that will cause it to block whilst work is running, but it was already waiting in that case (in `thr.join()`).  That makes the code much simpler:

```
static void threadLoop(worker *w)
    {
        auto endTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        std::unique_lock lock{w->mtx};
        while (!w->cv.wait_until(lock, endTime += w->duration,
                                 [w]{ return !w->keepWorking; }))
        {
            // Do some work
            w->f();
        }
    }
```

## Tests

There isn't even a simple `main()` to show how usable this is, or to demonstrate it working at all.

---

Modified code

```
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

// Func should be a function of no arguments
template<typename Func>
class worker
{
    std::thread thr;
    bool keepWorking;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    Func f;
    const std::chrono::system_clock::duration duration;

public:
    worker(Func f, std::chrono::system_clock::duration duration = std::chrono::seconds{15})
        : thr{&worker::threadLoop, this},
          keepWorking{true},
          mutex{},
          cv{},
          f{std::move(f)},
          duration{duration}
    {}

    void stopThread()
    {
        std::unique_lock lock{mutex};
        keepWorking = false;
        lock.unlock();

        cv.notify_one();
        thr.join();
    }

private:

    static void threadLoop(worker *const w)
    {
        auto endTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        std::unique_lock lock{w->mutex};
        while (!w->cv.wait_until(lock, endTime += w->duration,
                                 [w]{ return !w->keepWorking; }))
        {
            // Do some work
            w->f();
        }
    }
};
```

```
// Simple test program
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;

    auto task = []{
                    std::cout << "working..." << std::endl;
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(700ms);
                };
    auto w = worker{task, 1s};

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2400ms);
    auto const start_time = clock::now();
    w.stopThread();
    auto const time_taken = clock::now() - start_time;

    auto const millis =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time_taken);
    std::cout << "Thread stop took " << millis.count() << " ms\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the only useful point of this response is the *Excess complexity*. In summary: use `wait_until` and make sure to use the overload that accepts the `pred` argument, which solves the problem with `spurious wake-up calls` in a neat way.

Comment: Don't overlook the importance of keeping the condition variable locked while you're working, so that you don't have to deal with possible race after calling the work function.

Comment: And if you don't find *make a general utility* to be useful, then I'm sorry for wasting your time.